# Compare two hour strings Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, parse-platform

I have an string with an hour in it, for example "15:15", and an array of other hours in strings ex: @["15:00","16:00","17:00"] I should compare the single string with the array ones in order to get the ETA in a bus station, I tried this code but it keeps iterating and gives me the last greater value in the array, not the first greater value as I need.

```
int i = 0;
    horaArribada = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Horaris"]objectAtIndex:i];
    while ([hora compare:horaArribada]) {
        i++;
        if (i >= [[[objects objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Horaris"]count]) {
            break;
        }else{
            horaArribada = [[[objects objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"Horaris"]objectAtIndex:i];
        }
    }
    self.tfHoraArribada.text = horaArribada;
    }
}
```

Where objects is a query from Parse and hora the single string with an hour in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be doing a lot of extra work to iterate over your array. Instead, try a different format for your loop:

```
for (NSString *horaArribada in [[objects objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Horaris"]) {
  if ([hora compare:horaArribada] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    self.tfHoraArribada.text = horaArribada;
    break;
  }
}
```

This assumes that your `Horaris` array is already sorted such from smallest to largest. Also, the logic will not work for the midnight rollover, so you'll probably want to account for that.

Comment: Ok this works now, but I have another problem, imagine I select 18:45 the ETA should be 20:00 and it is, but if I select 19:30 it also shows 20:00 and it should be 20:45 because the journey takes 1:15h any way I can solve this? Thx

Comment: Add any offset to your `hora` before comparing it... You'll probably have to convert to `NSDate` or an `NSInteger` or something first.